# Embedded javascript, sending form data back to the application. Routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vuex, api-design

**Context**
Within an `rails app`, I created an embedded javascript form using `Vue`, external websites of `shops` cope/paste to let their website visitors search for available `bike_categories`.

**Goal**
Now I created the form they can copy/past and I would like to send the data back to my app, so I can search through my bike management app for the available bike_categories for the respective `shop`.

**Question/error message**
When trying to send the data back to my app, I get the following routing error, even tough the route is in my routing file. It's the first time I'm trying something like this, so I might be overlooking/missing something, but how can I solve this if the routing matches?

browser error

```
No route matches [POST] "/en/shops/66/shop_availability"

.....
available routes:

shop_availability_api_v1_shop_path  POST    (/:locale)/api/v1/shops/:id/shop_availability(.:format)   api/v1/shops#shop_availability {:format=>:json, :locale=>/en|nl|fr/}
```

console error

```
Started POST "/en/shops/66/shop_availability" for ::1 at 2020-02-27 09:15:24 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/en/shops/66/shop_availability"):

actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
request_store (1.5.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
webpacker (4.0.7) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:29:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (4.1.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.1.0) lib/puma/server.rb:664:in `handle_request'
puma (4.1.0) lib/puma/server.rb:467:in `process_client'
puma (4.1.0) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.1.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

**Code**

routes.rb

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :shops, only: [:show] do
      get :form_availability , on: :member
      post :shop_availability , on: :member
    end
  end
end
```

javascript/packs/embed.js

```
import TurbolinksAdapter from 'vue-turbolinks'
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import App from '../app.vue'
import store from '../store'
// store.dispatch('loadComments')

const event = (typeof Turbolinks == "object" && Turbolinks.supported) ? "turbolinks:load" : "DOMContentLoaded"

// Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter)

document.addEventListener(event, () => {

  const el = document.querySelector('#app-reservation-form')
  store.dispatch('loadComments')
  const app = new Vue({
    el,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
  })

  console.log(app)
})
```

javascript/vue

```
<template>
  <form id="app-reservation-form" action="http://localhost:3000/en/shops/66/shop_availability" ref="form">

    <div class="app-reservation-form-item">
      <h6>Arrival</h6>
      <input type="text" id="arrival" name="arrival" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="app-reservation-form-item">
      <h6>Departure</h6>
      <input type="text" id="departure" name="departure" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="app-reservation-form-item">
      <h6></h6>
        <button class="btn search-bikes-button">Search</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
    }
  },

  methods:{
    submit(){
    let formData = new formData(this.$refs.form)
    this.$store.dispatch("searchBikes", formData)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
p {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

javascrip/store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    bike_categories:[]
  },

  mutations: {
    load(state, bike_categories){
      state.bike_categories = bike_categories
    },
  },

  actions: {
    //show initial search form on website shop
    async loadComments({ commit }){
      let booking_url = window.location.href

      fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/shops/${encodeURIComponent(booking_url)}/form_availability/`,{
        headers: {accept: 'application/json'}
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => commit('load', data))
    },

    //Deal with data coming back from shops website
    async searchBikes({commit}, formData){
      let booking_url = window.location.href
      fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/shops/${encodeURIComponent(booking_url)}/shop_availability/`,{
        headers: {accept: 'application/json'},
        method: "post",
        body: formData,
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data))
    }
  }
})



window.store = store

export default store
```

models/shop.rb

```
class Shop < ApplicationRecord
def self.by_url(booking_url)
    uri = booking_url.split("?").first
    uri.sub!(/\/$/, '')
    # binding.pry
    where(booking_url: uri)
  end
end
```

controllers/api/v1/shops_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::ShopsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User, only: [:show]

  def show
    @user = current_user
    if @user.shops.find(params[:id])
      @shop = @user.shops.find(params[:id])
    else
      error
    end
    authorize @shop
  end

  def form_availability
    @shop = Shop.by_url(params[:id]).last
    @bike_categories = @shop.bike_categories
    render "shops/form_availability"
    authorize @shop
  end

  def shop_availability
    binding.pry
    @shop = Shop.by_url(params[:id]).last
  end

end
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console? I don't know vue but it looks like the main error is that handler on that form is not working and the form is just being sent normally instead of as an ajax request.

Comment: Thanks Max, just added the logs in my console to the question. following your advice I will look for solutions related to ajax requests in vue. Will post the solution here once I found one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe I missed it, the route in my form didn't contained the route to the normal `shops_controller` instead of the `api/v1shops_controller`.